# Print table from the top (column names, etc.) and then scroll down (Python)?

Tags: python, datatables

I am printing a table that is pretty long (printed with PrettyTable) and I want to show it from the top (where you can see the columns and the first lines) and then to scroll down like when you do `ps aux | less` 
How can I do that? Is there a module to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly this could be achieved with [Python Curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), but that's probably overkill at this stage.

I have two simpler options.

1. Print your table as normal, and then pipe it into `less`

```
$ python my_file.py | less
```

2. Print the table a little at a time, allowing the user to print more as they go. For this you need some list or generator of lines in the table.

```
line_index = 0
lone_block_size = 10
while line_index < len(lines):
    for line in lines[line_index:line_index+line_block_size]:
        print(line)
    line_index += line_block_size
    input()
```

This will print the first 10 lines, wait, and continue when you press enter.

Comment: The first option is good, but can I implement that into the code? The second one isn't working with PrettyTable because PrettyTable prints every time a new table for every entry